# c# I need to run a windowservice every sunday

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I need to run a window service every sunday only once in c#. I cannot use window
scheduler for that.How to use in c#.

Thanks

Comment: Windows services aren't supposed to be used like this afaik

Comment: Why can't you use the scheduler? Seems like the job it was born to do...

Comment: Why can't you use a scheduled task? alex is right - services are designed to run continually not a schedule/

Comment: yeah, I'd say create a console app to do the job you want the service to do, then schedule a task to run it every sunday

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/index.html), which is a task scheduling library that supports this scenario and many more.

It would still be much simpler to use the built-in task scheduler for such a simple scenario though...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) ,it's a great tool for scheduling Code ,and [Here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/restart-windows-service/) you can find an example how to run **Windows Service** from C#

Answer (score 1):

You could check the date in the onstart event of your service, and do nothing if the date don't match your requisites. You could also load when do you want to execute your code from a file. Save aso the last time your code was executed to avoid do the work twice the same day.

Comment: Great Idea , he can also use Quartz inside the Service if he's the Service Owner.